# Looking for resources regarding conveyor object allignment / object orientation

Tags: orientation, automation

Im currently on the hunt for resources / examples / words to use in a search engine in regards to **orienting (aligning, funneling) an object on a conveyor.**

I am looking for techniques / utilities used to 'line up' an object on a standard belt conveyor.  Essentially I have objects, boxes of the same size, coming in at some x,y position.  I would like to funnel (either passively with bars or objects, or actively with actuation) objects such that they are lined up in a specific position and orientations (straight at a single x,y position).

I have been looking for examples of such funneling however a lot of my queries `conveyor object funneling` `conveyor object orientation` `conveyor object alignment` are not yielding results withing the funneling realm.

[image: image of desired behavior where the purple lines represent a funneling system of any degree of sophistication]

**Im curious if there are keywords that I am missing in my research to find more examples, papers, vidoes, resources of such a task being completed**

If such a question is not encouraged in this community or if I am asking at the wrong stack exchange my apologies in advance.

Comment: This sounds similar to the work [Matthew Mason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_T._Mason) has done.  Although his research is more about manipulation than factory automation.

Answer (score 1):

The best option will be to use [Google Scholar(direct link)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=conveyor+orienting+items)  about item orientation on conveyer belts.

## General TIP

If "normal" Google doesn't return your results, try it via scholar.google.com